# Tree Subclass with node subclass?

Tags: java

I'm writing this in java.

I've got a BinaryTree Class. It has functions that use the Node class. 
I've written a subclass of Binary Tree (TraversalTree) and I've got a subclass of the Node class (OrderNode).

How do I get the TraversalTree functions that inherit from BinaryTree to use the subclass OrderNode??

```
public class BinaryTree {

  public Node root; // starting node of the tree

  public Node getRoot() {
      return root;
  }
}

public class Node {

  private int value; 
  private Node left, right, parent; 

  //constructor
  public Node(int value) {
      this.value = value; // data value to be stored in node
      left = null; // left child
      right = null; // right child
      parent = null; // parent node
  }
}
```

So here is the subclass OrderNode

```
public class OrderNode extends Node {

  public int preOrder,postOrder, inOrder;

  public OrderNode(int value) {
      super(value);
  }
}
```

And then in this subclass of BinaryTree, TraversalTree. I want it  to have the subclass OrderNode replace all the Node calls in the BinaryTree functions.

```
public class TraversalTree extends BinaryTree {

}
```

I've tried to search this a bunch but I'm hitting a wall. Perhaps I haven't been able to find the right search terms. But either way I can't seem to find any info on this.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: just use the node class.

Comment: Fair enough I suppose. Is there a situation one would want to extend classes like this?

Comment: If you want the two classes to behave differently, I see no problem with using inheritance. See yogesh's answer below, I believe this should be what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

You can use super to access the super variables and assign sub class object in super class reference variables.

```
class TraversalTree extends BinaryTree {
    public TraversalTree(OtherNode otherNode){
        super.node=otherNode;
    }
    public OtherNode getRoot(){
        return (OtherNode)super.getRoot();
    }
}
```

This should replace all node with otherNode.